# after cpanel upgraded to mariadb i can't connect to database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, mariadb

I have a dynamic website on my domain made using the codeigniter framework.

I don't know how cpanel upgraded from MySQL to MariaDB. Now when I open my website it says:

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings

I checked credentials ten time - they are correct. Then I checked db connection in using core php for testing, it also give an error:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

My user is not root and my password is not empty. It's not taking my credentials string correctly.

before this up-gradation it was working correctly.

Please help me what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

check your `mySql/mySqli/PDO` connection credentials, you have somewhere specified `root` as `username` and `host` as `localhost`,
and what about mariadb, it is a fork of MySql, see here... [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB)

Comment: where can I find this PDO path in cpanel ? I have database.php in cofig folder in codeigniter and there is the correct credentials i have given.

Comment: **PHP Data Objects (PDO)** is an extension which defines a lightweight and consistent interface for accessing databases **[wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#PDO)**  just like _MySql_ or _MySqli_, just dig in your code for database connection declarations' credintals for `root` and `localhost` **(simply ctrl+f 'root' or ctrl+f 'localhost')**